# How can I assign a separate class for each view in a ViewFlipper?

Tags: java, android, android-widget, viewflipper

I have a ViewFlipper that presents 3 different views.

Is it possible to have 3 classes manage* the 3 different views? If so, how do I go about doing this?

- For example, if View 1 shows a List of News and View 2 Shows a List of Prices, I want to have a News class that handles the interaction of the listview in News, and a Prices class that handles the interaction of the listview in Prices

Comment: How are you defining "manage the 3 different views"?

Comment: Updated my question to be more specific.

Comment: This is just Java. You can define whatever classes you like. If you want to create a `NewsPresenter` class that handles interaction with your `ListView` of news, you are welcome to do so.

Comment: but how do I map it out in the layout XML, so that NewsPresenter will load in the News layout etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you make your `News` and `Prices` class contain all of your application logic as you said. If you make them extend `ListView` you can then add them to your `ViewFlipper` and treat them in the same way, but they will have the specific behaviour as dictated by whatever you put in the `News` and `Prices` classes.

Alternatively, just set a different `listView.setAdapter()` [to populate], and `listView.setOnItemSelectedListener()` [to alter behaviour] for each ListView you have in your ViewFlipper.